# Editing a message while it's moved to other room aborts the move

Tags: bug, chat

So I was messing around in The Nineteenth byte and noticed a bug. If I go and hit edit on a message and it is moved to another room and post the "edit" the message just gets posted again in the original room. You can test this yourself on any room that you have a willing RO.

[image: Moved the message to Sandbox]

[image: And boom the message just posts]

Comment: Please post only 1 bug per question. Also, screenshots/caps would be helpful for illustrating what you mean.